# Setup Apache 2.2.19, MySQL 5.5.13 and PHP 5.3.6

Tags: php, mysql, apache-2.2

.Can anyone guide me in setting this things up. i can't seem to find a reliable source in the net. TIA!

> My OS is Windows XP 32-bit

Comment: What operating system?

Answer (score 2):

[Apahefriends.org](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/index.html) is hosting full Apache, Mysql and PHP packages for Linux, MacOS and Windows and should have all the information you need to install it.

Comment: .I think they promote XAMPP instead of installing individually.

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install WampServer 2 from http://www.wampserver.com/en/. It comes with a simple Windows installer and everything you need!